# My multilanguage menu for wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, menu, multilingual

I have a word press site and i need to add multi language. I've add the WPML plugin but i don't like how the menu for language is shown. I added manually in header.php in a div the two languages (En, It).
Is there anyway to add script so these two "buttons" to be my multilanguage menu?

Thanx in adv.

Comment: WPML is quite good at adding in the switcher automatically. To do this you will need to go through the settings option in WPML to tell it how and where to display the switcher. You should complete these settings anyway inorder to make sute WPML is able to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use a Twig templating engine to make a custom language switcher.

Here is a comprehensive [WPML documentation](https://wpml.org/documentation/getting-started-guide/language-setup/designing-custom-language-switchers-using-template-files/) on that topic.

Using the template example inside the article, you could modify it to something like:

```
<ul>
   {% for code, language in languages %}
<li class="{{ language.css_classes }} my-custom-switcher-item">
           <a href="{{ language.url }}">
           {{ language.code }}
           </a>
</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

WPML is quite good at adding in the switcher automatically. To do this you will need to go through the settings option in WPML to tell it how and where to display the switcher. You should complete these settings anyway inorder to make sute WPML is able to function properly.

However, you can add it manually, with the following code. Keep in mind that you will probably need to manually change the menu name to match that of your theme.

```
// Filter wp_nav_menu() to add additional links and other output
// Show only other language in language switcher
// Use the new filter: https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_active_languages/ 
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);
function new_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {
    // uncomment this to find your theme's menu location
    //echo "args:
<pre>"; print_r($args); echo "</pre>

";

    // get languages
    $languages = apply_filters( 'wpml_active_languages', NULL, 'skip_missing=0' );

    // add $args->theme_location == 'primary-menu' in the conditional if we want to specify the menu location.

    if ( $languages && $args->theme_location == 'primary') {

        if(!empty($languages)){

            foreach($languages as $l){
                if(!$l['active']){
                    // flag with native name
                    $items = $items . '
<li class="menu-item"><a href="' . $l['url'] . '"><img src="' . $l['country_flag_url'] . '" height="12" alt="' . $l['language_code'] . '" width="18" /> ' . $l['native_name'] . '</a></li>

';
                    //only flag
                    //$items = $items . '
<li class="menu-item menu-item-language"><a href="' . $l['url'] . '"><img src="' . $l['country_flag_url'] . '" height="12" alt="' . $l['language_code'] . '" width="18" /></a></li>

';
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $items;
}
```